# Is my CMS question appropriate for SO? Perhaps too localized

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, etiquette, too-localized

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for SO, or if asking which questions are appropriate is bad form on Meta, but here it goes.

My CMS seems to think that my front end: HTML, CSS, Javascript code may be causing an application error when I'm using their user interface. Is this even possible?
or in other words can front end code cause an application error in the user interface on a Ruby based CMS?

Hesitant to ask on SO as my CMS is really obscure (because it isn't very good), and may be seen as too localized.

Comment: I don't think too localized is going to be a problem, but you need to provide enough information with the question to make it answerable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure what I could add other than my code. I don't have access to their code, and I'd rather not name the CMS.

Comment: Just don't say "It doesn't work.  Here's my site: [link]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I think the best way is to simply make the best and clearest question you can, and post it.

In this case, as long as you can point to some particular piece of source code that breaks your website, it should work for Stack Overflow. If it's more of a configuration issue, perhaps [Webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)?

At the absolute worst, you'll get downvotes, and it's possible the question will get closed/deleted. You can also delete your own question yourself if you think you made a mistake! But really, a deleted question is not a big deal - [reputation from deleted questions won't keep, unless it's visible for more than 60 days](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/).

This trial by fire can be tough! But generally, you'll at least get some response (hopefully not too knee-jerk) to help point you in the right direction, or to help improve your question. Especially, if it's clear that your question is in good faith, and not PLZ GIMME TEH CODEZ :)

Comment: CMS questions seem to bring out a lot of knee-jerk reactions on SO. I'll try Webmasters.SE

Comment: Also its not exactly a code question its more of a "Is this even possible?"

Comment: Thanks for steering me to Webmaster.SE, found what I was after there.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't see that as problematic.  If your CMS has a tag associated with it, then that's clearly fine, and it's probably okay anyway.